# Considerations in board layout for different interface speeds

Tags: fpga, emc, layout, qspi

**Currently, I'm working on a design that includes four data buses operating at different datarates.**

The signals connect various parts of the system to the central FPGA. I have experience in designing PCBs around MCUs with relatively slower speeds (e.g., 16MHz SPI, 4MBaud UART, ...), but none with higher-speed interfaces (such as 96MHz Quad-SPI).

- 24MBit/s SPI
- 384MBit/s Quad-SPI (96MHz F-Clock)
- 48MBit/s UART
- 1MBit/s I2C

*All interfaces are running from 1V8 IO-Banks.*

The PCB is extremely small (15x3mm) and spans across six layers (Sig1, Sig2, GND, GND, Sig3, Sig4) with blind vias on the outer layers (Sig1-Sig2, Sig3-Sig4) and buried vias (Sig2-GND-GND-Sig3).

[image]

I do not think I have to take special care in length-matching or controlled impedance in the given example. However, I'm unsure about which aspects of routing I should pay special attention to.

**My question/s is/are:**

- Is the component placement (Top/Bottom) in respect to the bus-speed relevant? (E.g. Q-SPI component better on same side as FPGA or doesn't matter - don't care about ease of routing/only EMI perspective) for the Q-SPI and UART components?
- Is there a problem with stubs <5mm length (Think FPGA->FLASH->Testpoints) on the Q-SPI bus?
- Is there a problem with stubs <5mm length (Think FPGA->Transreceiver->Testpoints) on the UART bus?
- Is the layer-stackup optimal? (I was reading that SIG/GND/SIG/SIG/GND/SIG would be better)
- From what i described: What else did i not even think about?

Comment: What is the edge rate? What is the electrical length of that rate? What is the maximum trace/stub length?

Comment: Do you really mean 15x3 mm for the boards size?  That's like the size of half a soda straw flattened out.

Comment: @SteveSh Affirmative Sir - sadly so. High density design.

Comment: @TimWilliams The datasheet for the FPGA only states 155MHz max. I/O performance for 1V8 CMOS.

Comment: Most modern FPGAs have various drive strengths for the their output pads.  For instance it may be 4 mA, 8 mA, 12 mA, along with weak.nominal/strong.  For each combination of those parameters a good data sheet, from a reputable manufacturer, would provide the slew rates (1 ns, 20%  to 80%, for instance).  If your FPGA vendor doesn't have, or won't give you that information, you should look for another FPGA provider.